# SQL query IN using Ruby array

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays

I have an array in ruby 2.0.0, `@temp = [3, 4]` which I want to use in SQL `IN` statement. So I want the brackets (`[, ]`) to be removed.

My SQL query:

```
SELECT E.id,E.name, CEU.attempt, E.total_mark, CEU.has_attended as attendance, CE.id as categoryexamId, CE.examtype_id as examType, CU.id as categoryuserId, U.name as username

      FROM exams E
      Inner Join categoryexams CE on E.id = CE.exam_id
      Inner Join categoryexamusers CEU on CE.id = CEU.categoryexam_id
      Inner Join categoryusers CU on CEU.categoryuser_id = CU.id
      Inner Join categories C on CE.category_id = C.id
      Inner Join users U on CU.user_id = U.id
      Inner Join examtypes ET on CE.examtype_id = ET.id
      WHERE CE.category_id = #{category_id} AND CEU.has_attended = 1 AND U.id = #{user} AND CE.currentyear = #{academicYear} AND CE.examtype_id = #{examtype}" + (@temp.blank? ? "" : " AND CEU.categoryexam_id NOT IN (#{@temp})") +
      " Group By CE.id;
```

Comment: see here - http://archive.railsforum.com/viewtopic.php?id=14742

Comment: **Your code is insecure and has several [SQL injections](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)!!** See also the [Rails Guides section on SQL injection](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html#sql-injection)

Comment: I found it very difficult to convert this query in Rails Active record querying format. Can you please help?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

With Active Record, you can just use the array directly when using the "hash conditions" format, and it will automatically convert it to the right SQL:

```
MyModel.where(column: [3, 4])
```

See the Rails Guide on Active Record querying ["Subset Conditions" 2.3.3](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#hash-conditions)

Comment: Use Rails Active Record to create your queries as often as possible. This protects you from SQL injection attacks.

Answer (score 8):

If you want to use this as a string in where query. You can write it as:

```
@temp.join(',')
```

hopes, it will work.

Comment: -1 This allows adding further potential SQL injections to the query.

Comment: How do you even know the query will face user inputs ?